# Vertical HTML button spacing issues

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin, padding

I have three `<input type="submit" />` elements arranged vertically. The top two are in the same `<div>` and `<table>`, but the bottom one is in a different `<div>` and `<table>`. I can't change this, as it is for UX purposes in the context of the larger page from which this is just a snippet. My third button is an extra few pixels too low, such that the spacing between these three buttons is inconsistent.

I would like to not have to do a junky `vertical-align: -2px` or something like that. What I'd like is to gain some understanding as to *why* the spacing is inconsistent. Thanks for reading.

Here is a JSFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/y57wLtjb/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `border-spacing: 0;` for `table`

```css
table {      
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="pre-update-section">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input style="width:100%" type="submit" value="Check for duplicates" data-bind="click: CheckForDuplicates" id="btnCheckDups" /></td>
            <td><label id="ajaxStatusMsg"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input style="width:100%" type="submit" value="Load Catalog Parts" data-bind="click: LoadCatalogParts" id="btnLoadCatalogParts" disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    
<div id="start-update-section">
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td><input style="width:100%" type="submit" value="Run Catalog Update" data-bind="click: RunCatalogUpdate" id="btnRunCatalogUpdate" disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```